# Out of process RTD server

Tags: c#, excel, rtd

I'm trying to embed an RTD server into a preexisting C# application. The Microsoft docs state that the "RTD server can exist as an ActiveX DLL or **as an .exe that runs on the same local computer** or on a remote server. " so I do believe this is possible.

My RTD server is working ok, when I reference it from excel I get the expected value updating on a timer.

However, if I run the console application (expecting the embedded RTD server to be used) Excel seems to ignore it, and instantiate it's own in-process instance of the RTD server.

I've registered the exe using RegAsm (and of course the server class is COM visible). Is there some configuration that I'm missing? I'm finding the MS docs a bit lacking in this area....

Following links are all relevant:
[ExcelRTDServerinCS](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/11/10/ExcelRTDServerinCS.aspx) 
[client-other-than-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601997/excel-rtd-real-time-data-client-other-than-excel/3957357#3957357)
[MyRTDEXE](https://github.com/AJTSheppard/Andrew-Sheppard/tree/master/MyRTD/MyRTDEXE)

Comment: hey, was wondering if you found a solution to this, I'm running into the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

An RTD formula where no server is specified will always instantiate it's own instance of the dll, it seems that it's only in "remote mode" whereby it can use a .exe rather than a .dll.

I suggest that you try specifying the **local machine** in the server argument of the RTD formula (so it works with an executable).

(Also, make sure that you remove the progid registration from the original RTD dll if it exists.)